# Add an ID to first tr in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, dom, datatables

```
var row = [teams[i].team_id, teams[i].team_name,...];
var a = oTable.fnAddData(row);
```

I'm using [jquery datatables](http://datatables.net/) and adding teams data to datatables in above mentioned way, but I need the first column to be an auto increment one(I'll use a loop), but I want to add `team_id` as `id` for the `tr` element that carries this auto-incremented value in first column.

How do I add "id" to the `tr` while datatable is populated.

I need output as `<tr id="[team_id]">1</tr>`

Answer (score 1):

By including DT_Rowid as a property on the data source object, it will automatically create a table row id without any code whatsoever

For example, from an ajax source:

```
{
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": "57",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
  "aaData": [
    {
      "DT_RowId": "row_7",
      "DT_RowClass": "gradeA",
      "0": "Gecko",
      "1": "Firefox 1.0",
      "2": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "3": "1.7",
      "4": "A"
    },
```

Docs: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/ids.html

Note that DT_Rowid is case sensitive, so alias database queries with proper capitalization where necessary

Answer (score 0):

f there is no other table in the page you then you can use

```
 $('table').find('tr:first').attr('id',team_id);
```

or add an id to the table and say tableID

```
 $('#tableID').find('tr:first').attr('id',team_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The introduction of [jQuery API page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) says:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

So you may then use

```
$('tr:first').attr('id','\\[team_id\\]')
```